# How match ID number with CSS regexp

Tags: php, css, regex, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm customising a Wordpress theme and am stuck with the following CSS issue. I have a list of elements as follows:

```
li.block1, li.block2, li.block3, li.block4 {  top: 0; }
li.block5, li.block6, li.block7, li.block8 {  top: 150px; }
li.block9, li.block10, li.block11, li.block12 {  top: 300px; }
```

I'm generating the code using PHP and wish to use regexp to style these elements. I'd like to achieve the following:

```
- li.block[1-4] {style 1}
- li.block[5-9] {style 2}
- li.block[10-14] {style 3}
- and so on...
```

As I'm generating the `li.block[number]` dynamically based on user input, which could run into a few hundreds of elements, I believe that using regexp is the right way to go.

I've tried the following:

- Tried to use $ to match the last element, but I'd like some help on how to match on a range of values
- Tried using last-child attribute match, but as it's dynamic, I can't fix the last-child in advance
- Tried to use in-range to match the range, but I couldn't figure out how to check whether the number is in the range
- and, several other DOM matching criteria using CSS

I think the CSS match condition I'm using is erroneous, so I'd like to request experts in this forum to show me how to properly use $ and range:

How do I use regexp based on: `li.block[number,i, in range a-b] {Apply style number, i}`?

I'm also open to other ideas that help me keep the theme dynamic.

Thanks in advance,
Mithun Sridharan

Answer (score 2):

CSS don't know regexp, but you can use `~`:

```
li {top: 0;}
li.block4 ~ li {top: 150px;}
li.block8 ~ li {top: 300px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/auf56tgm/

Comment: Hey @panther, what is that (`~`) called? +1 nice answer

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: (general) sibling selector

Answer (score 2):

Another way is chaining `:nth-child` pseudoclasses e.g.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pg0c3qq3/2/

```
   li:nth-child(-n + 4) { top: 0 }
   li:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n + 8) { top: 150px; }
   li:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(-n + 12) {  top: 300px; }
```

Compared to the general sibling solution, every rule now just defines the style *only* to the expected range of `li` elements so, with this method every rule is not actually reverting the style applied from the previous rules.

Also this doesn't require to apply a specific `class` to each list-item so the markup can be simplified.